How to prefill lookup value in lightning web component
I have a requirement to create a task on opportunity with prefilled values from custom fields on the opportunity. I have a lightning web component on the opportunity detail page which I want to use fetch the fields and values trough apex since this is not achievable with custom actions. How do I get the name of a related record of the opportunity. I can get the id of the lookup field but I am not able to to do something like customfield__r.name in javascript. How do I achieve this?
The following only gives me the id
import { LightningElement, wire, api} from 'lwc';
import getRecord from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityController.getOpportunities';

export default class FetchDataFromApex extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    record;

    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId'})
    wiredAccount({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.record = data[0];
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('Something went wrong:', error);
        }
    }

    get Name() {
        return this.record?.Name;
    }

    get SalesContact() {
        return this.record?.SalesContact__c;
    }
}


@thomas
**Apex**

 @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
        public static List<Ambassador_Event__c> getAE(){
            return [select id,Ambassador_Event__r.Name from opportunity limit 2];
        }

**javascript**

import getAE from '@salesforce/apex/OpportunityController.getAE'
record;
@wire(getAE)
    wiredAE({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.record = data[0];
        } else if (error) {
            console.log('Something went wrong:', error);
        }
    }

    get Name() {
        return this.record?.Ambassador_Event__r.Name;
    }

**HTML**

<div>{Name}</div> //prints value of lookup field

